# How to route network traffic from one MacBook to another

Tags: macos, vpn, internet-sharing

I have two MacBooks. Let’s call them A and B. B is connected to vpn. I want to leave B at home and be able to use A outside but route traffic through B so I use vpn installed there and have access to everything I need. So not only local network but over internet.  Is it possible? If so, how exactly?

Comment: If B is connected via VPN to C, do you eventually want A to reach C or to reach C as well as B? If the latter, I think you need a second VPN.

Comment: I can reach C but VPN there is pre installed and I can’t move this config. Is there a easy way to run VPN on Mac OS?

Comment: I don't understand what is the answer to my question? How to run a VPN depends on the type of VPN, and of course, you will need all the configuration and access information.